# Tag synonyms: fingerboard, fretboard

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just created a [fingerboard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerboard) tag for fretless instruments. Should this be a synonym for [fretboard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fretboard) – or perhaps the other way around, based on the tag wikis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't expect these to be synonyms--I think it's reasonable to have questions that fit into one but not the other.